# application force to close

Tags: android-layout

> i cant understand this error coming in the logcat
>
> logcat error:

11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.example.orderplacemnet.Product_Details$MyProductAdapter.getView(Product_Details.java:75)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1198)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1109)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1012)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:381)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:526)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:304)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3132)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8171)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:801)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-20 18:45:42.125: E/AndroidRuntime(458):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

```
package com.example.orderplacemnet;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Product_Details extends Activity
{ 
            String[] text = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five"};

                int[] image = { R.drawable.rose_five, R.drawable.rose, R.drawable.rose_two,
                                                R.drawable.rose_three, R.drawable.rose_four};
                
                

                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {

                                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                                setContentView(R.layout.activity_product__details);

                                ListView l1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
                                l1.setAdapter(new MyProductAdapter(text,image));

                }
 class MyProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{

                                String[] data_text;
                                int[] data_image;

                                MyProductAdapter()
                                {
                                                data_text = null;
                                                data_image = null;
                                }

                                MyProductAdapter(String[] text, int[] image)
                                {
                                                data_text = text;
                                                data_image = image;
                                }

                                public int getCount()
                                {
                                                return data_text.length;
                                }

                                public String getItem(int position)
                                {
                                                return null;
                                }

                                public long getItemId(int position)
                                {
                                                return position;
                                }

                                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
                                {

                                                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                                                View row;

                                                row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, parent, false);

                                                TextView textview = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
                                                ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);

                                                textview.setText(data_text[position]);
                                                imageview.setImageResource(data_image[position]);

                                                return (row);

                                }
    }
}
```

> this is my layout of listrow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff200"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView01"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >

    </TextView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.76"
        android:contentDescription="@string/productlist" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 problems in your code.
First, the layout_weight property in the ImageView. You should specify the TextView layout_weight too. I recommend you to set the imageview weight to 3 and the textview to 1, so you don't need decimal numbers.

The second problem is pure guess: In the getView method from your adapter, try inflating without a parent:

```
row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, null);
```

hope it helps